# How do I rewrite the equation of the natural logarithm?

Tags: calculus

How can I require $c \ln c + c - 6 = 0 $ to $c = \frac{6}{\ln c + 1}$

I know that $c = 6 - c \ln c$. What's next?

Comment: I think that the question has a typo, this should be $\frac 6 {lnc + 1}$

Comment: Yup, I'll fix it now. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That'd be simple, you probably over-thought about it.

Take $c$ as common and you will get:

$c(lnc+1)=6$

$\implies c = \frac 6 {lnc+1}$

Comment: I definitely was overthinking it a bit too much. I feel stupid now. But thanks a lot!

Comment: @MathLove, happens with all, no problem, Consider marking the answer as correct though, Cheers! :)